# Populating a table with columns x and f(x) where f(x) is evaluated in a different cell

Tags: excel, function

I have created an Excel sheet so that when I enter a value x in cell C3, it returns a f(x) in cell D3 where f() is some complicated function (that constructs a set of random variables with parameter x, average them).  I have a set of values 1, 2, 3, ....10 in cells F1:F10. I now want to Excel to give me f(1), f(2),...., f(10) in cells G1:G10. More specifically, I want Excel to

1. take the value in Cell F1, substitute it in cell C3, get the value that would appear in D3, then enter it in G1
2. take the value in Cell F2, substitute it in cell C3, get the value that would appear in D3, then enter it in G2
   ...
3. take the value in Cell F10, substitute it in cell C3, get the value that would appear in D3, then enter it in G10

How to do it easily in Excel? I appreciate any insights or hints.

I am unable to simply enter the function in f() in cells G1:10 and then use the autofill option because function f() is too complicated that (it needs creating another table to evaluate f(x) for each x. That is why I want to solve it in the above way.

Comment: You would need vba to do this.

Comment: or just put the formula that is in D3 in G1 and use relative references to F1 then drag down and the reference will change

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.